# Return employee count based on relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a employees table and a attendances table

In employees Model

```
public function Attendance(){
    return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class, 'employees_id', 'id');
}
```

Attendances table i have these column
id, employees_id, in_time, out_time, attendance_status_id, remarks

I want return those employee who has al least one attendance for a specific month which i will input in month field and it will filter based on **in_time** column

Comment: what is the version of `Laravel` that you are using ? That makes a difference on how we could help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the has() function when getting the Employee details. The has will only return those records if the Employee has any relational data in the Attendance table. You can also refer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

```
$employees = Employee::has('Attendance')->get();
```

Now you can simply use the count() function the display the total Attendance of the Employee. For the count please refer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-count).

```
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
    Total attendance: {{ $employee->Attendance->count() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: In Controller
        $employee_list=Employees::query()->with("team")->select("id","name",'team_id')->Where('status',1);
        $employee_list->with(['Leave','Attendance' => function($q) use($month) {
            $q->whereMonth('in_time', '=', $month);
        }]);
        $employee = $employee_list->get();

Comment: Please update your query with this: `$employee_list = Employees::query()->with(['team', 'Leave'])->select('id', 'name', 'team_id')->where('status', 1)->has('Attendance' => function($query) use ($month) { $query->whereMonth('in_time', '=', $month);})->get;`